# Remove layouts except first one

Tags: android, android-layout

When the below method is called the dynamic layout will be filled to the parent_view.

```
public void Generate_tour_plan(String mark, OnClickListener o) {
        parent_view = (LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.tour_iternary_wrapper);
        hiddenInfo1 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.tour_plan, null, false);
        Button minus = (Button) hiddenInfo1.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        minus.setText(mark);
        CustomAutoCompleteTextView dealer_search = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) hiddenInfo1
                .findViewById(R.id.account_code);
        CustomAutoCompleteTextView town_search = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) hiddenInfo1
                .findViewById(R.id.town);
        town_search.setAdapter(city_adapter);
        dealer_search.setAdapter(adapter);
        minus.setOnClickListener(o);

        parent_view.addView(hiddenInfo1, 0);

    }
```

Here external layout will be added like a stack `eg.(5,4,3,2,1)`, so I need to remove all the layout except first one.

```
for (int j2 = parent.getChildCount() - 1; j2 > 0; j2--) {
                    Log.i("TAG IS", j2 + "");
                    ViewGroup vv = (ViewGroup) parent.getChildAt(j2);
                    vv.removeAllViews();

                }
```

Above code is for removing the items top to bottom.But this works on bottom to top. I want to remove the item like a  stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to call `removeViewAt(position)` like this:

> parent_view.removeViewAt(position);

Answer (score 23):

You can use the [ViewGroup.removeViews(start, count)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViews(int,%20int)) method.

To remove all child views/layouts except the first one:

`layout.removeViews(1, layout.getChildCount() - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a Child View from a parent by calling `removeView(View view)`, for example like this :

```
 parent.removeView(child);
```

Comment: Use for loop in reverse order

Comment: i used the reverse order as i mention in the edit.But nothing happens last added item remain always

Comment: I think you are missing just one step. Check your code meanwhile logcat

Comment: what do u mean by one step

Comment: Check your code & logcat, you'll get to know where is the problem. Check looping code

Comment: i check noting prints

Comment: I guess you are not refreshing/repainting your UI.

Comment: if i run the above code child's views are removed bottom to top.but i need to do it top to bottom except the 1 st one

Comment: print this parent.getChildCount() & its details(i mean view for particular count/position)

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = (your viewGroup).getChildCount() - 1;
for (int i = count; i > 0; i--) {
    (your viewGroup).removeViewAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do a very similar thing. In my case, I also needed to make sure the view fulfilled a certain condition before removing it, just to be sure. For what is worth, here is the Kotlin snippet for the same snippet posted by [Vijay Makwana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45325586/1269493):

```
    for(i in (childCount - 1) downTo 1) {
        val child = parent_layout.getChildAt(i)
        // before removing it, you can check something here
        parent_layout.removeView(child)
    }
```